# Boost MSM with constructor parameters on a submachine

Tags: c++, boost, boost-msm

I'm trying to share the `SyncBox` object between a main state-machine and a sub state-machine. The ideal way is to pass it on the constructor (sub state machine will be a initial state of one of the regions in a more complex case). No matter what, I can't make this code compile and execute properly. Any help?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/common.hpp>

namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace boost::msm::front;

class SyncBox {
    std::mutex mtx;
};

struct SubSMFE : public msm::front::state_machine_def<SubSMFE>
{
    struct InitState : public msm::front::state<> {};
    struct FakeState : public msm::front::state<> {};
    typedef InitState initial_state;
    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        Row < InitState, none, FakeState>
    > {};
};

//typedef msm::back::state_machine<SubSMFE> SubSM;
class SubSM : public msm::back::state_machine<SubSMFE> {
private:
    SyncBox& sb;
public:
    SubSM(SyncBox& sb) : sb(sb) { std::cout << "SubSMFE constructor" << std::endl; };
    void oneFunction() {
        // here i use syncBox. it must be a function of SubSM, not SubSMFE (oneFunction overrides start or enqueue_event)
    };
};

struct mainSMFE : public msm::front::state_machine_def<mainSMFE>
{
protected:
    SyncBox sb;
public:
    struct InitState : public msm::front::state<> {};
    typedef InitState initial_state;
    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        Row < InitState, none, SubSM>
    > {};
};

class mainSM : public msm::back::state_machine<mainSMFE> {
public:
    mainSM() : msm::back::state_machine<mainSMFE>(msm::back::states_ << SubSM(sb)) { };
};

int main()
{
    mainSM sm;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have the correct template argument to all your base classes?  Looks like a CRTP-type thing to me, so, for example, would expect `class SubSM` to pass itself as the template parameter to the base class

Comment: @wreckgar23 not sure what you mean

Comment: @wreckgar23 looks good to me. It's a CRTP but split-level (front end machine derived from backend defs)

Comment: @AndrewBloom I was talking about the template arguments being passed to the classes you were deriving your state machines from.  Compiling locally, the `transition_table` complains about `SubSM` not being default-constructable

Comment: I get "Error C2668 'boost::msm::back::state_machine<mainSMFE,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_,boost::parameter::void_>::state_machine': ambiguous call to overloaded function at MainSM() definition" on Visual Studio 2019 and boost 1.75.0 but I tried lots of variations and got some other bunch of errors like yours.

Comment: @AndrewBloom [state machine with constructor arguments](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s05.html#d0e2303) section might help you.  Not got it to work myself

Comment: @wreckgar23 yes that is what i'm kinda trying to do, except that it's fine for me to put the constructor and the associated data member on the backend. here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/examples/Constructor.cpp
the state empty has a default constructor defined. Seems to me that this is probably necessary (see your error) and it seems it doesn't like much the address-of operator. Changing to `SyncBox* sb;` and adding `SubSM() : sb(nullptr) { };` seems to fix it, except that i need to define `mainSMFE(int dummy) {};` to get rid of my ambiguous call. Any idea there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell you had everything correctly.

The problem, however, is that the substate-list requires all state elements to be default-constructible regardless. (This might not be true for the frontend class, as far as I can tell, but haven't looked all the way into it).

This means that storing a reference as member is off-limits. What I'd suggest instead is storing a pointer.

```
class SubSM : public msm::back::state_machine<SubSMFE> {
  private:
    SyncBox* psb = nullptr;

  public:
    SubSM() = default;

    SubSM(SyncBox& psb)
        : psb(&psb)
    {
        std::cout << "SubSMFE constructor" << std::endl;
    };
```

It does work as expected:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c3cb6f69eb74756)**

```
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
//#include <boost/msm/front/euml/common.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace boost::msm::front;

class SyncBox {
    std::mutex mtx;
};

struct SubSMFE : public msm::front::state_machine_def<SubSMFE> {
    struct InitState : public msm::front::state<> { };
    struct FakeState : public msm::front::state<> { };
    using initial_state = InitState;
    // clang-format off
    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        Row < InitState, none, FakeState>
    > {};
    // clang-format on
};

// typedef msm::back::state_machine<SubSMFE> SubSM;

class SubSM : public msm::back::state_machine<SubSMFE> {
  private:
    SyncBox* psb = nullptr;

  public:
    SubSM() = default;

    explicit SubSM(SyncBox& psb)
        : psb(&psb)
    {
        std::cout << "SubSMFE constructor" << std::endl;
    };

    void oneFunction() {
        // here i use syncBox. it must be a function of SubSM, not SubSMFE
        // (oneFunction overrides start or enqueue_event)
    };
};

class mainSMFE : public msm::front::state_machine_def<mainSMFE> {
  protected:
    SyncBox sb;

  public:
    struct InitState : public msm::front::state<> { };
    using initial_state = InitState;
    // clang-format off
    struct transition_table : mpl::vector<
        Row < InitState, none, SubSM >
    > {};
    // clang-format on
};

class mainSM : public msm::back::state_machine<mainSMFE> {
  public:
    mainSM()
        : msm::back::state_machine<mainSMFE>(
            msm::back::states_ << SubSM(sb)) {};
};

int main() {
    mainSM sm;
}
```

Prints

```
SubSMFE constructor
```

Comment: thanks @sehe, I reached more or less the same conclusion as per my comments at the question. I'm puzzled that your code compiles with g++, I tried the same with Visual Studio and it raise still the error. In my opinion could be a bug (I posted it on the bug tracker of msm here: https://github.com/boostorg/msm/issues/33) do you have any thought about it? I found as temporary workaround to have a constructor with a dummy parameter on mainSMFE.

Comment: Can you share the code that works? Perhaps we can test here https://godbolt.org/z/8bse6r Good idea to file an issue as well. It might be an MSVC issue in the end.

Comment: this is the code with the workaround for me working: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52cad36200f6b95b . the workaround is adding line 44 and changing line 54.This seems to solve the ambiguity on the constructor call.